# identifying objects and labelling not working "built-in method all of ..."

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, numpy-ndarray

Basically, I have a numpy array in which I want to label different objects and for each object, want to find the maximum assigned (original) value and centre of mass.

I've managed to label my array and I've tried to use extrema to find my max values but I'm running into an error I don't understand.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import generate_binary_structure, label, find_objects, extrema

s = generate_binary_structure(2,2)
ft_object = np.asarray(label(ft2, structure = s)) #ft2 is originally a tuple which is why I perform np.asarray
print ft_object
```

Since this gives me a tuple, I convert into a numpy.ndarray again and perform the extrema function to get the maximum values.

```
ft_extrema = extrema(ft_object)
```

This gives error message saying

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

So I change it to

```
ft_extrema = extrema(ft_object.all)
```

This works but when I `print ft_extrema` expecting some result, I get this in return:

```
(<built-in method all of numpy.ndarray object at 0x2b90d09ed0d0>, built-in method all of numpy.ndarray object at 0x2b90d09ed0d0>, [()], [()])
```

Not entirely sure how to solve this or why it's doing that so would appreciate any help or advice.

I also want to use `find_objects` to splice my objects separately to find the `center_of_mass` for each object separately but I'm unable to get that far.

Comment: Try adding () after `ft_object.all`

Comment: @DanielNudelman it gives me the same error message as earlier `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that by the documentation `label()` returns a tuple and the actual labels are in the first place and they are already an nparray.
I don't have your `ft2` object but let it be for example

```
ft2 = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1]])
```

Then I would edit your code in the next way:

```
import numpy as np #same
from scipy.ndimage import generate_binary_structure, label, find_objects, extrema #same

s = generate_binary_structure(2,2)   #same
ft_object = label(ft2, structure = s)[0]   #here take only the first object, these are the labels
ft_extrema = extrema(ft2, ft_object)   #here you should give as an argument the input and the labels
print ft_extrema
```

And the output is:

```
(1,1,(0,0),(0,0))
```

As expected, because 1 is the max and the min